# Function to display fortnight

Tags: ms-access

Can someone help me do this same function I did in excel in Microsoft Access?

I want according to the column Date it returns me if it is in the 1st or 2nd fortnight of the month

Excel example: `=se(DIA(A1)=<15;"Primeira Quinzena";"Segunda Quinzena")`

Comment: A fortnight is 14 days so you really mean period before or after 15th of month. Some months will have more than 14 days in the second period.  You have a field that has just the day number? Calculate in query or textbox: `IIf(fieldname <15, "Primeira Quinzena", "Segunda Quinzena")`

Comment: No, I only have a field with the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy, I would not like to add a field only with the day, as it would be possible without adding the field day

Comment: Calculate the day number: `IIf(Day(fieldname) <15, "Primeira Quinzena", "Segunda Quinzena")`. Seems only differences between the Excel and Access expressions is Access uses IIf() and Excel uses If() and Access references a field instead of cell notation.

Comment: A _fortnight_ is 14 days, not _the half of a month_. That is a [semimonth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortnight).

Comment: @Enigmativity, 
It's giving a syntax error, it could simplify for me, I have a day column already returning the day, I just want you to say in the next column if it's the 1st or 2nd fortnight.